# Cohomological criterion for semi-ampleness

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An invertible sheaf $L$ on a scheme $X$ is:

-$\textit{ample}$ if for every coherent sheaf $F$, $F\otimes L^n$ is generated by global sections  for $n$ sufficiently large depending on $F$,
-$\textit{semi-ample}$ if $L^n$ is generated by global sections for $n$ sufficiently large,

so in my head semi-ampleness is ampleness but only for $F=\mathcal{O}_X$ (maybe this is a bad viewpoint?)

With the due assumptions on $X$, there is a well known cohomological criterion for ampleness (Proposition III.5.3 in Hartshorne), which says: $L$ is ample if and only if for every coherent sheaf $F$ one has \begin{equation}
H^i(X,F\otimes L^n)=0
\end{equation}

for every $i>0$ and sufficiently large $n$ depending on $F$.

Is there a similar cohomological criterion of semi-ampleness?

Comment: Well, there is the equivalent condition $L$ semiample on (proper $R$-scheme, $R$ noetherian) $X$ iff $\bigoplus_n H^p(F,L^n)$ is a finitely-generated graded module over the graded ring $\bigoplus_n\Gamma(L^n)$ for all $p\geq 0$ and all coherent $O_X$-module $F$.  Or maybe you want an alternative: the restriction $L_B$ of $L$ to the stable base-locus $B$ of $L$ is ample?

Comment: I suppose the "semi-ampleness is ampleness for $F = \mathcal O_X$" perspective makes about as much sense as anything else. But the "right" way to think about semi-ampleness, I think, is that just as an ample line bundle is "eventually very ample" since a large power produces an embedding (despite the initial bundle potentially not even having sections), a semi-ample line bundle is "eventually base point free" since a large power produces a morphism (despite the initial bundle having nonempty base locus).